# Why is my use of the ?: conditional operator incorrect?

Tags: java

I get a compilation error while trying to compile, "not a statement", and the code is:

```
(checkDatabaseExist())?connectToDB() : buildDB();
```

when the functions are:

```
private boolean checkDatabaseExist() {...}
private void connectToDB(){...}
private void buildDB(){...}
```

any ideas?

Comment: You can't use the ?: conditional operator with void methods. You must return something from the statement.

Comment: Use `if/else` instead of `?:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can't use the [conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) like that. It's intended to compute one *expression* or another as a result. It's not intended to be a way of choosing one *statement* to execute or another.

Just use:

```
if (checkDatabaseExist()) {
    connectToDB();
} else {
    buildDB();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [JLS - Section 15.25 - Conditional Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25): -

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand
>   expression to be an invocation of a void method.

So, you must use an `if-else` construct to invoke your methods on different condition.

```
if (checkDatabaseExist()) {
    connectToDB();
} else {
    buildDB();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator can not be used with methods/operations returning **void**.

The methods/expressions must return a value compatible with the reference type.

Comment: As I commented earlier, it is not **the** ternary operator, it is **a** ternary operator. This, specifically, is the conditional operator. =)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Jon Skeet said, a Ternary operator (What you're using) is designed to be used in this sort of way:

```
String s = someBoolean ? "someBoolean is true" : "someBoolean is false";
```

`(condition) ? (value if true) : (value if false)`

Comment: It's not **the** ternary operator. It is **a** ternary operator. It is, however, **the** conditional operator.

Comment: Technically, it's a Conditional Operator.